# Issue with multer and router.post(). cannot read property 'any'

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a multer issue when I am trying to use it my `.post` path.
My route looks like this:

```
const fileUpload = require('../middleware/fileUpload');

router.post(
  '/projects/create/:userId',
  authCheck,
  isAdmin,
  addProjectToUser,
  fileUpload.any(),
  create
);
```

And my file upload is:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/jpg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
};

const fileUpload = multer({
  limits: 500000,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, 'uploads/images');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      cb(null, uuidv1() + '.' + ext);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let err = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid Mime Type!');
    cb(err, isValid);
  },
});

module.export = fileUpload;
```

I do get `const photUpload = fileUpload.any(); TypeError: Cannot read property 'any' of undefined`

Not sure wht is worng with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports = fileUpload;`

Notice the extra `s` in exports